# SQLite3 — Return Affected Rows

Tags: jdbc, sqlite, transactions

Supposing I have a schema with a name field and an int field. I want to get one random entry where the int value is 1, set it to 0, and return the name of the entry that was changed in a transactional manner. What's the best way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do something in a transactional manner is with a [transaction](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ID, Name FROM MyTable WHERE IntValue = 1 ORDER BY Random() LIMIT 1;
UPDATE MyTable SET IntValue = 0 WHERE ID = ?;
COMMIT;
```